# Patterns or techniques to avoid dereferencing a field on an undefined object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I work on a large Angular/Typescript project and I very frequently encounter such errors as:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property ‘completeness’ of undefined
```

This happens for example in a create/update form when used in create mode when the object (i.e. a `plan` here) is still `undefined`.

See:

```
if (this.plan.completeness === 'COPYING') { //plan is undefined in create mode
...
```

We then go to fix the problem as follows:

```
if (this.plan && this.plan.completeness === 'COPYING') {//Ensure plan is truthy regardless of whether it is in create or update mode
...
```

Note this can also happen with nested objects such as:

```
const person = {name: 'John', address: {country: 'UK', street: '10 Downing Street'}}
```

If `address` is `undefined` and I try dereferencing the `street` as follows:

```
person.address.street;
```

I will obviously get the same kind of `TypeError`...

Our codebase contains a tremendous amount of checks such as:

```
if (person && person.address & person.address.street) {
  // do something with the street
}
```

I find this lame and noisy.

Quite independently of the above specific cases, I am looking for more elegant patterns or techniques to reduce this kind of dereferencing errors.

Any hint or pointer are welcome.

Comment: If this is happening you aren't using the compiler effectively; it needs to know when a value might be undefined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your reply. Can you please kindly elaborate on you comment? Perhaps by providing examples.

Comment: See e.g. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties, http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters

Comment: There's a nice article (by Nadeesha Cabral) here: https://codeburst.io/how-to-handle-deeply-nested-nullable-fields-in-javascript-and-typescript-5ef3f38c92d9 proposing several solutions amongst which optional chaining upcoming in typescript 3.7.